# how to improve high load time in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am getting very high load time in magento 2 even I have the best score in all aspects how to improve load time I am on magento 2.3.4 Kindly help [image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at No. of request your website making means you have use Javascript bundling.

That what increases your load time. because that bundle js is larger in size as well as contains all js ( Useless for particular page ) get load.

Actually it also increases TTFB.

Please refer to this [Link](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/javascript-bundling-magento-2/)